# How to distinguish the original Google Analytics code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

first piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7078796-5']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();</script>
```

second piece of code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-67264568-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I saw this code on my website I think it was added by the webmaster but I want to know which one is the original or whether both codes are needed.

Comment: Top one is classic analytics bottom one is is universal analytics they are both writing to two different google analytics accounts.

Comment: Not sure if both codes are present on the same page, the original language was unclear. However you can see that 2 different GA ids are used so they may have 2 different owners and be used for different purposes.